# caddy server: protect dynamically generated files with different passwords

Tags: webserver, password-protection, caddy

I created an app that creates brain tumor segmentations. Once the segmentation file is generated users receive a download link to it via email. Every generated download link should use its own password. How do I configure caddy to handle this use case?

I know I can protect single directories / files with this:
https://caddyserver.com/docs/basicauth

Ideally I could place a file containing the required password in the directory with the .zip archive and generate that when I also generate the zip archive.

The .htpasswd file seems to serve this purpose but in the docs it says:

> Support for .htpasswd is for legacy sites only and may be removed in the future; do not use .htpasswd with new sites.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to get Caddy to do this, then you could use a `.htaccess` file if that works for you and just understand you will probably need to provide an alternative once caddy 2 is released.

Additionally you could use a php file to intercept the download and check the password before allowing access to the file.

Comment: thanks for the answer would you have an example how to approach this in php?